# Is it wrong to let your cat give love bites?

Tags: cats, behavior

Whenever I get bored I start playing with my cat. And probably it's her favourite past time too.

I tickle my cat, she bites me gently and then starts licking me.

I bring my hand slowly from various angels to quickly touch her. My job is not to let her bite and her job is to anyhow bite.

Sometimes when I am sitting and she is playful mode she suddenly comes running and starts biting my toe.

Sometimes when I am walking she also moves along with me, all the time jumping and biting my toes.

I think she gets immense pleasure in biting me.

I have already vaccinated my cat with all sorts of vaccines.

Now the negative part is at times the biting really hurts and there is cut on skin, though I don't mind it at all.

Now my question is that is it all right to allow my cat do this or should I stop playing with her like this.

Also is this behaviour normal for her?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer, yes.  Once in a while wouldn't be so bad, but it sounds like this is a regular thing.  If that is the case you are TRAINING your cat that your body parts are a toy.  That's probably not your objective.  I would strongly suggest redirecting to an actual toy (mouse on a string for example) that is an appropriate outlet for your cat's catch-kill-eat instinct.  This is normal behavior in the sense that your cat is responding as a normal cat would to prey.  I just doubt that you really want your cat to view your toes as prey.  As a side note, vaccinating your cat isn't going to protect YOU.  Your cat's mouth is filled with tons of bacteria; if the skin is broken from a bite or a scratch you can end up with a bad infection.

Comment: I did not have any idea about infection. I thought vaccination is enough. During play I regularly get skin cuts from my cat's teeth and nails. I simply apply anti-septic liquid and nothing else and brush it off.